# Why does a basic Drupal view return no results

Tags: drupal

I am starting out with views and I wrote an extremely simple view which really just filters if the node is published and if it is of type banner. In preview and when I try to print the view I get no results. When I search through my content and filter by type banner and published, I get 3 results (in /content/node/overview). I must be doing something basic and stupid, any suggestions for how I can figure out what I have done wrong?

View:
http://www.randomcrapilike.com/test/view_capture.jpg

Content Search:
http://www.randomcrapilike.com/test/contentsearch.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bouncing around a few mailing lists and playing around I have found out that sometimes a view preview will not work with just the default display. If you notice it not working, try adding a new display. Another thing I tried was to just adding and removing comment fields and it magically began working.

In the future I will and I suggest to anyone that has a similar problem:

1. Add a new display, see if that resolves it, If it does not:
2. Recreate the view with just one filter and one field, get that to work and add complexity until you find where it breaks.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings. One more approach for debugging views: take the generated query and run it directly against the database (eg. with a custom php file or in phpMyAdmin). If that does return the correct results, it's likely to be a problem with your views templates or the display style (ie. the output-side of Views configuration).